# Lenovo T14 Gen 1 No Mic and Sound

Tags: 20.04, pulseaudio, alsa, thinkpad

I have the Intel version and I'm using Kernel 5.4.0-58-generic with 20.04.

Those are my recent logs:

```
11:16:42 gdm-session-wor: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
11:16:33 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS
11:16:31 kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.HIDD._DSM due to previous error (AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE) (20190816/psparse-529)
```

This is my `pulseaudio` version 13.99.1 and the -D output:

```
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon startup failed.
```

Answer (score 1):

For me the installation had no issues. I just had to select the right card (hidden) in `alsamixer`, unmute it and raise its volume (zero by default).

```
$ alsamixer
```

[image: alsamixer, initial display]

Press `F6`

[image: sound card choice dialog]

Choose the sound card (in my case, `sof-hda-dsp`)

[image]

Use the arrow keys to choose the `master` channel, raise the volume and unmute with `M`.

Answer (score 0):

After much digging I found out Alsa does recognized my mic and Pulseaudio does not, not sure why.

But I combined several steps that solved the issue for me:

1. I removed Pulseaudio:

   sudo apt-get purge pulseaudio

   sudo apt-get purge pavucontrol

   rm -rf ~/.pulse/
2. Reboot (after rebooting, no input or output device were found).
3. Add the following to **/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf**

   blacklist snd_hda_intel

   blacklist snd_soc_skl
4. Add the following to **/etc/pulse/default.pa** (note replace the device with your own device address)

   load-module module-alsa-source device=hw:0,0
5. Reinstall Pulseaudio:

   sudo apt-get install pulseaudio
6. Reboot.

After finale reboot all input and output devices were working including internal Mic and Audio.

- Part of the solution was taken from [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=249900).